# 3 table join in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a game where users play different game and can choose their roles within each game(like team fortress).

I have created a 2 table join "games_users"

```
create_table "games_users", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "game_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end
```

And managed to establish HABTM relationships between the games and users

game.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

user.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :games
```

I would like to add now a roles model(or even a roles string) to the system with a 3 table join , how do I do this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what you mean by a 3 table join?  Do you mean a table that associates a user, role, and game as a single record?

Comment: i need to be able to get from the games table the users and their roles within each game they have played, and from the users table get the games they have played and the roles within each game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the `games_users` table with a `roles` table and have a `has_many :through` between `User` and `Game`, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :games, :through => :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, :through => :roles
end
```